# How to update a field of an object inside an array inside an object in MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I am developing a Node.js application using MongoDB as a database. I have created a collection called users and the structure of it is as below:

```
{
  username: 'Alex',
  email: 'alex@test.com',
  password: '123456',
  cart: {
    items: [
      {
        productId: 574894734,
        quantity: 1, 
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

When the user clicks on the "add to cart" button, I want to check if the cart already contains the product. If it contains the product I want to increase its quantity otherwise I want to add it.

I've tried a lot of solutions on StackOverflow but I couldn't solve the problem.
I get duplicated items in the cart object.

Help me.

Comment: This is an answer I wrote last month with similar issue (update the field in an array or insert if not exists); you will find it useful: [mongodb insert data into the array of objects and update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675838/mongodb-insert-data-into-the-array-of-objects-and-update-it).

Comment: I didn't learn mongoose yet

Comment: The code I had posted there was _not_ mongoose; it is using [MongoDB NodeJS Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/).

Comment: I couldn't understand it, can you rewrite the code to match what I look for, please?

Comment: I suggest you try that yourself, first. And, post the difficulties you face in programming your solution. Note that, there are examples of programming with NodeJS Driver with the link I had provided in my previous comment. _Also_, here are more examples at [MongoDB Blog - NodeJS CRUD Operations](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-video-nodejs--mongodb--the-crud-operations).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: @Bug : Do you need a mongo query or entire node.js + mongo code ?